# Where to place helper specs (specs that test additional things in a Rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Not to be confused by the title, I am not asking where I can place specs that test Rails helpers, but helpers specs that test additional things in a Rails app. For example, a spec that checks whether all translations are in place. Or that FactoryGirl factories are valid.

I know the guys at FactoryGirl recommend putting this check on RSpec's `before :suite`, but I prefer to leave it aside in a spec file of its own (so that it doesn't get executed when I want to run a single spec, for example).

So, what's *the* place to put these kind of specs?

Answer (score 0):

I put FactoryGirl's specs in `spec/models/*_spec.rb`. For example

```
# spec/models/user_spec.rb
describe User do
  describe "factories" do
    it { expect(build(:user)).to be_valid }
  end
end
```

For other kinds of specs, say for service objects, I put them in `spec/services/*_spec.rb`. RSpec will automatically detect them.

## Edited

For translations, I test them in view specs. Firstly, set config to raise error on translations are missing.

```
# config/environments/test.rb
# Raises error for missing translations
config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
```

Then in the view spec,

```
describe "pages/welcome" do
  it { expect { render }.not_to raise_error }
end
```

Comment: They are neither model specs, nor service specs, please read my question again. I wouldn't have asked this question if the answer was so obvious :) .

Comment: I would like an utility spec to test that all translations are there, not for a specific view, which should indeed reside in view specs. The utility spec simply doesn't fit there...

Comment: It's not model specs, I suggest you to put factory specs in models spec. Anyway, updated the answer. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Not quite...my examples don't fit well in your solution. I was looking for something more natural :)

Comment: I don't understand what "natural" means... Take a look at i18n-tasks gem https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks